# How can i get the UUID of my IPHONE in an application?

Tags: ios, database, uuid

I am developing an application with external databases. For this motive, I have to save an uuid the only identifier for every user who registers. This way, it will differ if the user is a new user or is a user already registered in the application.
I create a new uuid with this:

NSUUID  *uuid = [NSUUID UUID];

And i save that at external databases with the username. How do I obtain this information when the user enter again to the application? Have I to save it in some place of the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you could could use `NSUserDefaults`

**To cache uuid:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:uuid forKey:@"userIDKey"];
```

**To retrieve uuid:**

```
NSString *uuid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userIDKey"];
```

Note that using the `NSUUID` class restricts you to an iOS target of iOS 6.0+.  There are other ways to generate a UUID < iOS 6.0, e.g.

```
+ (NSString*)stringWithUUID {
    CFUUIDRef uuidObj = CFUUIDCreate(nil);
    NSString *uuidString = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuidObj);
    CFRelease(uuidObj);
    return uuidString;
}
```